# Code ran before every action within symfony

Tags: php, symfony1

I have code that I want to be executed before every action is called.  Are there action hooks I can use for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a module:

```
public function preExecute()
{

}
```

If you want it to be global for all modules, put it in the appConfiguration class, or create a filter.

Comment: I put it in my backendConfiguraiton class, but it didn't execute.  I'm using v1.4.3-DEV if that makes a difference.  Thanks.

Comment: it looks like filters may be the way to go.  Thanks for the direction.

Answer (score 1):

+1 for filters. events can also be very useful, depending on what you want to do.

Comment: I would -1, but you are new. Comments go underneath answers, so that questions aren't bumped to the top. :) Edit: maybe you need some reputation points to write comments.

Comment: @Coronatus. duly noted. thanks. yes, I'm new :) there wasn't an 'add comment' for the previous answer; I didn't realise my post would register as a wholly different answer. something new learned every day...